# Android - findViewWtihTag returns null

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-identifiers

The findViewWithTag in this activity is returning null, but the Log in the CustomExpandableListAdapter outputs correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

//normal stuff

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild,
View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    CustomObject group = (CustomObject) getGroup(groupPosition);
    //normal stuff

    LinearLayout toggle = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.toggle);
//group.getId() returns an int
    toggle.setTag("toggle" + group.getId());
    Log.i("BBBBBtoggleadapterBBBBBB", toggle.getTag().toString());


    return view;
}


}



public class MainActivity extends BaseListActivity {

//normal stuff

//this is an xml onClick
public void toggleView(View view) {

  String groupId = view.getTag().toString();
  //LinearLayout toggle = (LinearLayout) view.findViewWithTag("toggle " + groupId);
   Log.i("BBBBBBBBBtoggleactivityBBBBBBBBBB", "toggle" + groupId);

    /*if (toggle == null) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/

}
```

}

edit:updated code, Logged "toggle" + id in activity and adapter and they are identical

Comment: Did you compare the log print with "toogle " + groupId? Maybe skip the whitespace after toggle?

Comment: I went back and Logged "toggle" + id in the activity and adapter and they are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. findViewWithTag looks for child tags that match. The LinearLayout I was trying to identify is not a child of the button who's onClick triggered toggleView. So, I needed to go up (2 levels, in this case) to find it.

```
View parent = (View) view.getParent().getParent();
LinearLayout toggle = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewWithTag("toggle" + groupId);
```

Comment: Also, in case you don't know which parent it is you can also use `view.getRootView().findViewWithTag(tag);`

Answer (score 0):

Your tags aren't the same.  `"id " + group.getId()` != `"toggle " + groupId`

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo when I posted it. That are both "toggle" + id
Well, in the activity it's + groupId
and in the adapter it's + group.getId()

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code?  Also, have you tried logging the tag that you are setting and the tag you are trying to get to make sure that they are the same?  Maybe you could include those printouts in your question as well?